# Проблемы с доступом к ВК с яблочных устройств.

Tags: роутер

На Air'е вк не грузит. У соседа с айпадом те же проблемы. Раньше раздавал инет с виндоус ноутбука через connectify - не грузил. Купил zyxel роутер, создал точку доступа - то же самое. Все остальные сайты грузятся нормально. На виндоус ноутбуках вообще никаких проблем. Через чужие точки доступа на вк заходит без проблем. С чем это может быть связано?

Интернет общажный... Может тут какие-то завязки?

Comment: А что говорит пинг на:    87.240.188.252    87.240.188.254

Comment: делаюping [ip.adress]он работает пока я Ctrl+C не нажму.Потеря - 0%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением следующих строк в /etc/hosts:

93.186.224.246 [vk.com](http://vk.com)

93.186.227.126 [login.vk.com](http://login.vk.com)

Почему работает не знаю =) Если кто подскажет - буду признателен!

Comment: Так, СТОП! Для макбука проблема решена, но с айпадом все по-старому!Видимо есть какие-то особенности точки доступа... Ведь с через другие тд все работает.

Comment: попробуй вводить в браузер вместо vk.com айпишник сайта

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.